# Sort Object HashMap (not by key)

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

So I have several objects in a HashMap: `private HashMap <String,Object> hmap;`

what I want to do is sort this objects through a variable of the objects (a double). How should I do this? I think I'm required to use comparators, but I don't know exactly how to work with them. Should I send the objects to an array?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: what do u mean by 'through a variable of the objects'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will need to do sorting in a separate List. You will need something like below:

```
List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
values.addAll(hmap.values());
Collections.sort( values, new Comparator<Object>(){ 
 public int compare(Object o1,
                   Object o2){
    //do specific comparison here
 });
```

Comment: notice that the 'compare' function must return positive values when o1 > o2, negative value when o1 < o2, and zero when o1 == o2

Comment: List<String,Object> is this really exists in Java?